# C# Wrapper Library SendToContact Property

Tags: c#, xero-api

I'm using version 2.2.1.13 of the c# Xero.API.SDK.Minimal nuget package. On the Invoice class (Xero.Api.Core.Model) there's a nullable boolean property named SendToContact. Does anyone know what this is and/or what it does? I'm not seeing it referenced anywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"SentToContact" is a boolean to indicate whether the invoice in the Xero app displays as "sent" (from the docs - https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/invoices).

It doesn't trigger any kind of sending mechanism.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks Rusty. Turns out I was searching on SendToContact, should have written SentToContact.